# Using PIXI.JS a dependency in a ES6 TypeScript API

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, pixi.js, rollupjs

I'm creating an TypeScript Graphics API and would like Rollup to bundle in Pixi.js. I have pixi.js installed as a npm package and am referencing it from my .ts file as such:

```js
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
```

Rollup (with the TypeScript plugin then warn me):

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
pixi.js (imported by src/lib/DropJoystick.ts)
```

and my browser reports an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “pixi.js”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

It's clear to me that Rollup is clearly not bundling PIXI with my TypeScript API in that the browser is now looking for the mode module name ("pixi.js").

How do I go about ensuring that RollUp / TypeScript bundle Pixi?